# Can be done with JavaFX alone

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have app that uses jintellitype.jar and DLL with Java environment. This is because I need sometimes full not showing of app.

Can be done in JavaFX just using Java and not DLL?

Comment: does not compute! What is the question?

Comment: Please explain what you want to do in brief words.

Comment: The question is about having the application changed to full screen mode using keyboard shortcuts in Java and disrepair competently. Now I want to change JavaFX without jintellitype.jar and DLL.

Comment: @Aayush, I have window witch disappears, that I am using DLL and jintellitype.jar. Question is JavaFX is ready to work this way just in  JavaFX language.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the question is about having the application changed to full screen mode using keyboard shortcuts (and not using `JIntellitype.dll`).

It seems possible in JavaFX using the approach I found [here](http://thierrywasyl.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/keyboard-shortcuts-and-mnemonic-in-javafx/). The example considers to have a `MenuBar` and its items, e.g. the `MenuItem` for FullScreenMode. Haven't tried it, but it seems not be dependent on the presence of an equivalent for `JIntellitype.dll` or anything else.

Comment: Could you write program just use Java and not XML?